# R big.matrix operators

Tags: r, r-bigmemory

I am after little help trying to find the particular position of a value within a big.matrix object. Take the following matrix:

```r
X <- as.big.matrix(matrix(1:30, 10, 3))
```

I want to find the row and column number where a particular value occurs, say
`find_numb = 13`
(this will be later used to subset against another matrix). On a standard matrix I do:

```r
as.matrix(X) == find_numb #Convert big.matrix and find location of value
```

Which returns a `TRUE/FALSE` matrix which is great.

Now, when I do the same on a big.matrix
`X == find_numb`
I get the following error:

```r
Error in X == find_numb : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

This seems like a simple problem but I do not fully understand the error (still learning R / programming in general), so I apologize for not understanding these atomic and list definitions to solve myself.

The above example is of course a simplified example: the actual matrix is around 500 GB (hence big.matrix), and I want to search through a vector of different numbers to find their individual locations e.g.

```r
find_numb <- sample(1:10000, 2000).
```

I have the the mcapply function drafted to do this, just striking this issue when trying to find the initial locations of each value.

Thank you for any help and guidance

Comment: Have a look at all functions of the package with `help(package = "bigmemory")`. I think `mwhich()` is what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried using 'mwhich()' but that only returns the row number, not the column position as well...I will try knocking something up by transposing the matrix perhaps.

Comment: Yeah, I can't manage to make it work. Maybe you can ask about it by opening an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With R package {bigstatsr}, you can do:

```
library(bigstatsr)
X <- as_FBM(matrix(sample(30, 5000, replace = TRUE), 50, 100))

# tuto for big_apply(): https://privefl.github.io/bigstatsr/articles/big-apply.html
test <- big_apply(X, function(X, ind) {
  res <- which(X[, ind, drop = FALSE] == 13, arr.ind = TRUE)
  res[, 2] <- ind[res[, 2]]
  res
}, a.combine = "rbind")

test2 <- which(X[] == 13, arr.ind = TRUE)
all.equal(test, test2)
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of the package.